# Google Cloud Function + bigquery: Internal Server Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

I'm making a Google cloud Function with python that requests data to an API, perform an ETL, and finally put the resulting panda's dataframe in a big query table.

The deploy is correct, but when I trigger the function (HTTP trigger) I get this error:

```
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.
```

Any idea of what I'am doing wrong??? Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from google.cloud import bigquery, error_reporting
from bigquery_tools import update_table

def main(request):

  if request:
    try:
        # BIGQUERY CLIENT
        BIGQUERY_CREDENTIALS = "credentials.json"
        BIGQUERY_PROJECT_ID = "my_project_id"
        BIGQUERY_DATASET_ID = "my_dataset_id"
        TABLE_ID = "my_table"
        CLIENT = bigquery.Client(project=BIGQUERY_PROJECT_ID)

        # SOME DATAFRAME
        df = pd.DataFrame({
            "debug": ["debug_a"]
        })
        
        # SAVE TO BIGQUERY
        try:
            dataset_ref = CLIENT.dataset(BIGQUERY_DATASET_ID)
            table_ref = dataset_ref.table(TABLE_ID)
            job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
            job_config.source_format = bigquery.SourceFormat.PARQUET
            job_config.autodetect = True
            job_config.write_disposition = bigquery.WriteDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE

            job = CLIENT.load_table_from_dataframe(
                df,
                table_ref,
                job_config=job_config
            )
            job.result()  # Waits for table load to complete.

        except Exception as e:
            pass
    except Exception as e:
        pass
```

Comment: Can you share your dependency version, the size of the data that you get from the API and the set up of your Cloud Function (memory, region,...)? Thanks

Comment: I solved my question: the problem was that I forgot the statement return ('some message', http_code). For example : return ('ok',200)

Answer (score 1):

**[SOLVED]** the problem was that I forgot the statement `return ('some message', http_code)`.

For example : `return ('ok',200)`

```
        try:
            dataset_ref = CLIENT.dataset(BIGQUERY_DATASET_ID)
            table_ref = dataset_ref.table(TABLE_ID)
            job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
            job_config.source_format = bigquery.SourceFormat.PARQUET
            job_config.autodetect = True
            job_config.write_disposition = bigquery.WriteDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE

            job = CLIENT.load_table_from_dataframe(
                df,
                table_ref,
                job_config=job_config
            )
            job.result()  # Waits for table load to complete.
            return ("ok", 200)
        except Exception as e:
            return ("error", 400)
```